# Oracle prevent CPU usage per process/session

Tags: oracle, process, session

I have an Oracle instance to which several applications from different machines connect (http servers). Normally Oracle CPU usage is ~5-10% even on high server loads. But from time to time, one of http servers impose high (100%) CPU load on Oracle, which causes other oracle clients (in the case other http servers) timeout and do not work properly.

Is it possible to limit CPU usage on a per process or per session basis? Or is it possible to limit CPU usage for clients connected to oracle from a special Machine/IP?

Comment: [Oracle Resource Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/dbrm.htm)

Comment: Theoretically you can you resource manager for CPU but it does not have good reputation. The other solution is to reduce the size of the connection pool for application which do not behave good.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Enable Resource Manager
ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN = 'DEFAULT_PLAN' SCOPE = BOTH;

-- Create a new Resource Manager Plan
CREATE PLAN low_cpu_limit;

-- Create a Consumer Group for limiting CPU
CREATE CONSUMER GROUP low_cpu_group;
ALTER CONSUMER GROUP low_cpu_group
  MODIFY CPU_PER_SESSION LIMIT 20; -- Change 20 to desired CPU limit percentage

-- Create a mapping rule to map sessions to the low CPU group
BEGIN
  DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.CREATE_PLAN_DIRECTIVE(
    PLAN                  => 'low_cpu_limit',
    GROUP_OR_SUBPLAN      => 'low_cpu_group',
    SWITCH_GROUP          => NULL,
    COMMENT               => 'Low CPU limit for sessions'
  );
END;
/

-- Activate the new Resource Manager Plan
ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN = 'low_cpu_limit' SCOPE = BOTH;
```